# PHP loses mongoDB cursor despite long timeouts

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm running a long mongoDB query like this:

```
foreach($xyz->find(...)->timeout(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)->maxTimeMS(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) as $document) {
    ...
}
```

But despite those 24 hour timeouts for the client and the server, the script exits with a `MongoCursorException` after a few minutes:

> localhost:27017: could not find cursor over collection xyz

I'm on PHP 5.4 with the v1.6.10 mongoDB driver. The DB is mongoDB 3.0.4. PHP will connect to a mongos instance, the collection `xyz` is sharded.

Any idea what may cause this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there are more timeouts which are not all supported by PHP (yet). One of them is [maxIdleTimeMS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#maxIdleTimeMS):

> The maximum number of milliseconds that a connection can remain idle in the pool before being removed and closed.

What happened in my case was that, due to the database being busy at times, this long running query was idle for too long so its cursor got dropped server-side.

Setting this parameter would've helped but since it's not available, I've found that what solved the problem was to decrease the [batch size](http://php.net/manual/de/mongocursor.batchsize.php):

```
$cursor->batchSize(-20)
```

In this example, at most 20 documents are transferred between the server and the client for each batch. This reduces the probability that the connection is idle for too long. Of course, the exact value depends on the load of your database, how long you need to process each document etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say, I have similar experience, I have a collection which I look trough via

```
$items  = $col -> find(['data' => 'OK']);
$items->timeout(-1);
$items->maxTimeMS(3600*1000);
```

but after walk trough via

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
   ///... processing
}
```

after about 12 - 15 minutes, I get the same error

```
could not find cursor over collection
```

In the collection, there is about 150000 records, and the interesting fact is, that the error always appears after processing 123479 records, regardless the content of the 123480th record and regardless the time spent by the processing of the respective records (time necessary for processing the record can vary depending on the content).

As I cannot find any cause of the error, after several tries to improve mongo settings, including upgrade of driver for PHP, I am now doing whole process in batches, which prevents losing the cursor. It works fine, however, I would like to know the more clean solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I had tried with last version of two drivers,

- PHP 5.6 x86 Non Thread Safe (Windows)
- https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo version 1.6.14
- https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb version 1.1.9

***find*** method return a cursor. I'm not sure the way this work but this cursor doesn't have all the documents. Need ask mongo to get the next one ans after a time conection broke.

The solution to me was use the method [toArray](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-cursor.toarray.php) of [MongoDB\Driver\Cursor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php) (Driver [mongodb](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb))

This return an array with all documents. I have a batch that works with more than 100k documents without problems.