# MongoDB and PHP Library Cursor Timeout

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

While using official MongoDB's PHP Library (https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/install-php-library/), how to set the cursor timeout as infinite? I read mixed documentation and it's often hard to understand if it refers to the old PHP Driver or the new one (which I am talking about).

For instance:

```
$cursor = $col->find();
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
   // slow code..
}
```

How to prevent the cursor from timing out (see error below) and making sure the cursor is closed afterwards without any memory leaks?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException: 
cursor id 123456789 not found in /var/www/html/code.php:1
```

There are some similar questions here (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129112/php-loses-mongodb-cursor-despite-long-timeouts)) but it seems we lack a definite reference.

Comment: Have you tried setting `noCursorTimeout` option (although not a good idea because  setting cursor timeout as infinite as will keep the cursor open for forever) for find operation or specify `batchSize` for query ?

Comment: re noCursorTimeout .. but then how to close the cursor manually? just setting this option to true seems to be just half of the solution?

Comment: I agree that is not even a recommend option. I'm afraid I don't know a way to close the cursor from client side ( may be cursor.close when error is intercepted ) but one can set timeout on the server. Something like `mongod --setParameter cursorTimeoutMillis=time in millis` kills the cursor after a timeout. What about the other solution ? using batchsize ? Set to lower number so your slow code have enough time to run and request the results frequently on the server.

Comment: Which PHPLIB version are you using ? Also, did you try to set `batchSize()` as mentioned on the other post ?

Comment: I use: MongoDB server version: 4.0.1 / pecl mongodb 1.4.3   stable / Library is probably 1.3.2. I have not fiddle yet with batchSize as I am debating as to whether that will cause races in my code. But your point is understood. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cursor id 123456789 not found in /var/www/html/code.php:1

Typically this is because the application is spending too long between [getMore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getMore/) commands. In other words, the cursor returns a number of records on the first iteration and the loop takes a long time before it requests more records.

```
$cursor = $collection->find( [ 'field' => 'foobar'] );
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    // long running processes (slow)
}
```

Cursors have a timeout on the server, after ~10 minutes if the client has not sent any commands to the server it will be closed due to inactivity. In the case above, when it's requesting for the next batch, the cursor has been killed resulting in the error message `cursor id not found`.

Some tried to disable the cursor timeouts by setting `noCursorTimeout:true` on the cursor. Although this is not recommended, because you may end up with a cursor that lives forever (zombie) when there's an issue with `getMore` results returning from the server. i.e. cursors with `noCursorTimeout` may remain alive on the server long after the client disconnected.

There are a couple of possible solutions:

- Decrease [cursor.batchSize()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/). This is because reducing the number of records per batch reduces the cursor inactivity. i.e. Previously 100 records processed for 15 minutes, now it's only 50 records for 7.5 minutes.
- Manually create a session i.e. [PHPLIB MongoDB\Client::startSession()](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBClient-startSession/). Then pass this as a `session` option on the queries. At regular intervals during the long-running iteration, perform some other database interaction using the same session i.e. [ping](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/ping/) the server. This will keep the `session` active (30 minutes timeout); however, it will do nothing to keep the cursor alive, so you may combine this with the use of `noCursorTimeout`.